# What exactly is a function or mapping? Is it an object?

Tags: group-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

What exactly is a function or mapping? Is it an object?  I'm not talking about the domain or the codmain which I know are Sets and therefore objects. The mapping itself, what is it? From what I understand everything is a set, but a function is made of two sets plus something else. What is that something else?  As far as I understand in ZFC everything is a Set.

From Abstract Algebra  by Dummit and Foote

"A group is an ordered pair (G, *) where G is a set and * is a binary operation on G satisfying the following axioms:  ..."

"A binary operation * on a set G is a function $* : G \to G$."

What is confusing is that I just finished learning ZFC Set Theory and it shows that an ordered-pair is the Set:

(x,y) = { {x}, {x, y}}

When the y is not set a but a function now I'm confused of how "(G, *)" can be an ordered pair when the * is not simply a Set.

Comment: In ZFC, everything is a set: a relation or a function is (modelled as) a set of pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's also a set. A function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$ is a subset $f$ of $A\times B$ such that, for each $a\in A$, there is one and only one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

Comment: Makes sense I guess f(x) = x + 2 is imply the set of ordered pairs { (1,3),(2, 4), (3,5), ... }